# Adding two polynomials in python

Tags: python

I am trying to add two polynomials here. The polynomial class is given after this code. The problem I am facing is getting poly2 into a dictionary format (STEP 2 of the 2nd code)

```
def create(string):
    p = Polynomial()
    for word in string.split():
        nums = word.split('x')
        p.add_term(float(nums[0]), int(nums[1]))
    return p

poly1 = create("1x3 1x4")
poly2 = create("-1x2")
poly = poly1.add(poly2)
```

This is the Polynomial class:

**class Polynomial:**

```
def __init__(self):
    self.power2coeff = {}

def add_term(self, coeff, power):
    self.power2coeff[power] = coeff

def __str__(self):      
    result = ''
    for power, coeff in self.power2coeff.items():
        result += '{:.2f}x{} '.format(coeff, power)
    return result

def add(self,poly2):
    poly1=self.power2coeff   **#STEP1**
    poly2=?                  **#STEP2**
    *code to add poly1 and poly2*
```

The problem is with the poly2 variable. How do I get it in dictionary format? For example, in the function "add", the poly1 variable is in dictionary format when I set it the way it is in step1. But I cannot figure out how to get poly2 the same way.

Comment: What's wrong with `poly2.power2coeff`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer that worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

poly2.power2coeff worked for the above code!